# Cannot start diaspora server anymore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, sigterm, diaspora

**I had no problem with my diaspora pod until several hours ago.
Diaspora went off and since then, it has been impossible to turn it back on.**

**First, here is my terminal output :**

http://pastebin.com/PZeusSsK

---

**Output of : /script/get_config.rb server.rails_environment**
=> production

**Output of : echo $RAILS_ENV**
(blank space)

**Output of : echo $RACK_ENV**
(blank space)

---

**This is the end of my sidekiq.log :**

http://pastebin.com/Ep9s02Tb

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried rebuilding all your RVM Ruby gems?

`gem pristine --all`

(from https://superuser.com/questions/489582/how-to-rebuild-all-my-ruby-gems)